# .htaccess prevents POST form from working

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I noticed that after transferring my files from localhost to development server my form no longer works (it works perfectly fine in the local environment). It seems to me that it's because of the .htaccess contents.

The relevant form code:

```
<form id="formbuilder" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/add_entry.php">
```

and the .htaccess contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there any way I can alter the htaccess in a way it will let me update my post request? At the moment when i check it in dev tools, the request ends on 'add_entry.php'.
Thanks for any hints,
S.

Answer (score 0):

This htaccess would not prevent `get_template_directory_uri()/add_entry.php` from executing, assuming that whatever `get_template_directory_uri()` returns plus `/add_entry.php` is the actual path to this add_entry.php file on your server. If it doesn't exist, it will map the request to index.php, which may be what is happening.

You might find something like [this](http://glennmessersmith.com/pages/wphtaccess.html) to be helpful.